# jquery adding new div on button click only if previous div's textbox value is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a new div one after one upto 10 "div", and each div has three textboxes.
Everytime I want to add new div only when the 3rd textbox value of previous div is not blank !!!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add Booking</button>
</div>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 2;
    $(".add_field_button").click(function() {
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div id="target"><label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
            '" id="firsttextbox' + counter + '" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
            '" id="secondtextbox' + counter + '" value="" >  <a href="#" id="remove_field">Remove</a><input type="text" id="box' + counter + '" value="">this is 3rd textbox of each div</div>');
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

        counter++;

    });
    $(this).on("click", "#remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('#target').remove();
        counter--;

    });
});
</script>
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the value of last div of the previous group than check this

```
var boxid="#box" + (counter-1);
var prev_value=$(boxid).val();
if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }
        else if(prev_value == ""){
            alert("please fill the box");
            return false;
        }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/3rr97osd/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).is(":empty")){ 
    //Create new div
}else{
    alert('div should not be empty');
}
```

never done this but after some googling this is what i came up with hope it helps